# Why are seemingly stable parts (i.e., with $(\partial P/\partial V)_T<0$) of the Van der Waals' isotherms also excluded?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

Certain unphysical region of the isotherms obtained from of the Van der Waal's equation of state must be excluded because, in this region, volume increases with increasing pressure (i.e. $(\partial P/\partial V)_T>0$) and therefore, violates the thermodynamic stability.

However, in reality, a slightly bigger region is excluded by Maxwell's tie line construction which contains part of isotherms for which $(\partial P/\partial V)_T<0$. But these parts of the isotherms do not immediately seem to be problematic. Is there any physical way of understanding why some thermodynamically stable regions with $(\partial P/\partial V)_T<0$ are also excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *metastable* regions. They are stable in the sense that $\partial P/\partial V)_T<0$, but when the system is in these regions, it can lower its energy by *phase separation*.

Comment: Phase separation, as I understand, happens when the system is abruptly quenched to regions of pressure and temperatures that correspond to the unphysical region negative compressibility, and not those corresponding to the metastable region you mentioned. Isn't it? @fra_pero

Comment: @SRS, fra_pero is correct. There will be phase separation on the whole interval given by Maxwell's construction. (Actually, it would be more correct to say that Maxwell's construction is valid precisely because phase separation is occurring. That's why it is not valid in mean-field models.)

Comment: I thought that the gas can enter the extra region on the right, if the pressure is increased very slowly and coaxed to stay in a supercooled state in the absence of perturbations. @YvanVelenik

Comment: In a lab, yes. But it is a metastable state. If you leave the system for long enough, phase separation will occur (when the system reaches its true equilibrium state). You can accelerate this relaxation to its true equilibrium state by, say, shaking the system or perturbing it in other ways. This is why you need, as you say, to increase the pressure very slowly.

Comment: @SRS. I should point out that even the *existence* of these metastable branches is a nontrivial issue. Namely, one can *prove* that in lattice gases (with short-range interactions), the pressure has an essential singularity at the transition point. In particular, the pressure cannot be analytically continued beyond this point, which implies that the "metastable branches" are not uniquely defined (there are infinitely many ways to smoothly extend the pressure beyond the transition point (that is, in a $C^\infty$ manner), which are dynamically relevant).

Comment: Thus, the "metastable branches", as such, do not exist in this type of models (and thus, presumably in general fluids with short-range interactions). That they appear in the van der Waals model is because the latter is of mean field type (and thus cannot support phase separation).